# How would I write a query to count the number of records created in a specified amount of time in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have some basic SQL experience but am seeking to do some data reconciliation on an Oracle database, hence the query i'm writing will be in PL/SQL.

Having run a performance test, I would like to find out how many records were inserted, and how many were updated over a period time `(just over 2 hours)` in total in the schema.

Is there a simple way of writing a query that does the following.

```
 - Displays a count for records inserted
 - Displays a count for records updated
 - Alongside the Table name
```

So in summary, the table would be 3 rows, and my time period is as follows.

```
between to_date('16-01-2015 13:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and to_date('16-01-2015 15:30:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a feature called Change data capture, that can help you

Comment: Hi Koushik, wouldn't need a time column as the query should only return results if they were created/updated between 13:00 and 15:30.

Comment: @Saravanan Unfortunately wrt to CDC that hasn't been setup previously on all of the tables so would require a lot of interaction with the dba, i'm looking for a simpler and quicker solution at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: If your setup has flashback, you can use flashback version query ( http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01004 ) if the time period you are interested in is sufficiently recent, so that redo/undo is present in the flashback area. If you need more permanent, you might schedule a nightly job to store results of flashback query into a table with for example hourly insert/update/delete statistics.

Comment: The `ora_rowscn` might help you http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm

Comment: @KimBergHansen -  Tried that, as we had flashback enabled but didn't have permissions to query the flashback. DBAs didn't want to assign the permissions so had to close off this option. Thanks very much for your suggestion, will consider it for future projects.

Comment: @Exhausted - Tried but unfortunately ora_rowscn didn't provide enough granular detail at that time for what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.